# Switch to vim like editor interactivelly to change a Python string

Tags: python, vim, curses

I have the following source code:

```
import sys, os
import curses
import textwrap

if __name__ == "__main__":
  curses.setupterm()
  sys.stdout.write(curses.tigetstr('civis'))
  os.system("clear")
  str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" * 10 # only example
  for line in textwrap.wrap(str, 60):
    os.system("clear")
    print "\n" * 10
    print line.center(150)
    sys.stdin.read(1) # read one character or #TODO
    #TODO 
    # x = getc() # getc() gets one character from keyboard (already done)
    # if x == "e": # edit
    #    updatedString = runVim(line)
    #    str.replace(line, updatedString)

  sys.stdout.write(curses.tigetstr('cnorm'))
```

The program moves through the string by 60 characters.
I would like to have editing possibility (in the #TODO place) in case
I want to change the string just displayed.

Is it possible to open a small `vim` buffer when I press a key? I would make an edit and when I press `:w` it would update the string. I would like the `vim` editor not to change the position of the string in the terminal (I'd like it centered).

Comment: It is possible! It is possible to open a buffer, edit and save. Updating the new buffer's content will be little bit difficult. Are you okay with different solution. For example, after opening a new buffer, once you edit it, you can copy entire thing by pressing `ggvG` and then copy by `y` and  paste in place of to do, by pressing p

Comment: @SibiCoder Every solution is worth trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def runVim(ln):
  with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".txt") as tmp:
    tmp.write(ln)
    tmp.flush()
    call(['vim', '+1', '-c set filetype=txt', tmp.name]) # for centering +1 can be changed
    with open(tmp.name, 'r') as f:
      lines = f.read()
  return lines


...
x = getch()
  if x == "e":
    updatedString = runVim(line)
    str = str.replace(line, updatedString)
print str
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Idea:**

Let us choose `\o` and `\w` for our purpose.
Keep the cursor on "TO DO" or any other word you like and press `\o`.
Then, it opens new tab. You can write anything in new buffer and then press `\w`. It will copy the whole thing and close the buffer and then pastes in the cursor position in current buffer.

**Mapping**

```
   :nmap \o cw<ESC>:tabnew<CR>
   :nmap \w ggvG"wy:tabclose<CR>"wp
```

Comment: OK, I tried it. But this is something different, then I was asking in the question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly: you can't do it that way.  Programs generally cannot read what you printed to the screen.

You *could* make a program which displays text on the screen and (knowing what it wrote) pass that information to an editor.  For instance, `lynx` (an application using curses) displays a formatted HTML page on the screen, and provides a feature which passes the content of a form text-field to an editor, reads the updated file from the editor and redisplays the information in the form.